# How do I drop all empty tables from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

How do I drop all empty tables from a MySQL database, leaving only the tables that have at least 1 record?

EDIT: This is what I did using Python 3 with mysqlclient

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='localhost', user='root',
    passwd='mypassword', db='mydatabase'
)

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SHOW TABLES')
for row in c.fetchall():
    table_name = row[0]
    c.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {table_name}')
    if c.rowcount == 0:
        # c.execute(f'DROP TABLE {table_name}')
        print(f'DROP TABLE {table_name}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And a PHP version for completeness. It won't drop anything, just print for you the DROP statements:

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="mypassword";
$database="mydatabase";
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

function drop_empty_tables(){
    $tables = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($table = mysql_fetch_array($tables)){
        $table = $table[0];
        $records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
        if(mysql_num_rows($records) == 0){
            // mysql_query("DROP TABLE $table");
            echo "DROP TABLE $table;\n";
        }
    }
}

drop_empty_tables();
?>
```

Comment: haha im an idiot... looked at this and tried it and was like why the **** wont they tables drop. Missed the comment. Thank man, worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

Use [pt-find](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-find.html) from Percona Toolkit:

```
$ pt-find --dblike "mydatabase" --empty --exec-plus "DROP TABLE %s"
```

Answer (score 4):

This stored procedure should do it:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `drop_empty_tables_from` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `drop_empty_tables_from`(IN schema_target VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    DECLARE table_list TEXT;
    DECLARE total      VARCHAR(11);

    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(`TABLE_NAME`),
        COUNT(`TABLE_NAME`)
    INTO
        table_list,
        total
    FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
    WHERE
          `TABLE_SCHEMA` = schema_target
      AND `TABLE_ROWS`   = 0;

    IF table_list IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @drop_tables = CONCAT("DROP TABLE ", table_list);

        PREPARE stmt FROM @drop_tables;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;

    SELECT total AS affected_tables;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

There may be problems with that `GROUP_CONCAT` when there are too many empty tables. It depends on the value of the [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable.

It's not possible to do it in one query because `DROP TABLE` cannot receive its arguments from a `SELECT` query.

#### InnoDB note

Thanks to **James** for his comments. It appears that the row count query won't return precise results in the case of InnoDB tables, so the above procedure is not guaranteed to work perfectly when there are InnoDB tables in that schema.

> For InnoDB tables, the row count is
>   only a rough estimate used in SQL
>   optimization. (This is also true if
>   the InnoDB table is partitioned.)

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Very nice; that's a bit shorter and more elegant than mine... I had forgotten there was a table_rows field.

Comment: However... for InnoDB is it guaranteed that `table_rows` field is zero only if the table is empty?  (I would think this would be one of the few times where the `table_rows` for an InnoDB table would be correct, but I don't actually know).

Comment: James, it appears it's not guaranteed to be precise, even in this case.

Answer (score 1):

- If "empty" means entries with "" `IF (SELECT * FROM tablexy) DROP TABLE tablexy`
- If "empty" means not any entry `IF (SELECT * FROM tablexy) DROP TABLE tablexy`

(You have to run this queries for each table, because I did not found a way to perform one query on all tables in one query)

It is the same query, but I want to differ from NOTHING and SOMETHING WITH NO CONTENT ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of the php-script posted earlier, 
I added a function that loop through all databases (and as the original script, uncomment mysql_query() when you want to run the script for real)

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="mypassword";
$database="information_schema";
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database\n");

function find_databases() {
// edit the query if you want to add more databases that you dont want to mess with
$databaseq = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(SCHEMA_NAME) FROM SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME not in ('information_schema','mysql','phpmyadmin');");
    while($databaser = mysql_fetch_array($databaseq)){
        echo "Checking $databaser[0] ...\n";
            drop_empty_tables_and_db($databaser[0]);
    }
}

function drop_empty_tables_and_db($get_database){
    mysql_select_db($get_database) or print( "Unable to select database $get_databas\n");
    $tables = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($table = mysql_fetch_array($tables)){
        $table = $table[0];
        $records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
        if(mysql_num_rows($records) == 0){
            echo "DROP TABLE `$table`; \n";
            //mysql_query("DROP TABLE `$table`") or print( "Unable to drop table $table\n");
        }
    }
    $tables = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    if(mysql_num_rows($tables) == 0){
        echo "DROP DATABASE `$get_database`;\n";
        //mysql_query("DROP DATABASE `$get_database`") or print( "Unable to drop database $get_database\n");
    }
}

find_databases(); //...and remove them :)

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If used straight from the shell, replace db with database_name.  Note this is live, no uncommenting needed.

```
db='wordpress_db';
for f in $(mysql -e "use $db;SHOW TABLES;" | sed 's/^| \([^ ]*\).*$/\1/g'|sed 1d);
do 
   c=`mysql -e "use $db;SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${f}\G"|sed '/:/!d; s/^[^:]*: //g'`;
   [[ $c == 0 ]] && { echo "DROP db.$f" && mysql -e "use $db;DROP TABLE $f"; }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using PHP is:

```
#connect to database first

$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `".$database."` 
WHERE ENGINE IS NOT NULL
AND `Rows`=0";
if($res = mysql_query($sql)){
    if(mysql_numrows($res)){
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $table = $r['Name'];
            echo '<br />'.$table;
            if($ret = mysql_query("DROP TABLE `".$table."`")){
                echo ' = DROPPED';
            }else{
                echo ' = '.mysql_error();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This removes another execution just to determine that the table has no rows.

I'm getting problems with the `GROUP_CONCAT` using the stored procedure. What's strange is that some tables are not recognized of they are not found it seems.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  $tables = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES');
            $i = 0;
                while($table = $tables->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
                    $table = $table[0];
                    $records =  $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
                    if($records->num_rows == 0){
                        if ($conn->query(" DROP TABLE `$table` ")){
                           $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
       return $i;
```

variable $i show count of table deleted